# Website redirection intermittently work in Firefox but not work at all in IE

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, 301-redirect

After few try an error in website redirection, I manage to perform website redirection but it intermittently works in Firefox but not work at all in IE. I manage to clear all cache and retry in Firefox and it works, but weirdly it does not work after that. I confirmed that I wasn't doing any changes on any files at that time. Did anyone have any idea or face this before? I was sooooo happy that my website finally redirects even I was happy like 2 minutes then it turns up wasn't redirect again. :(( I just need it to redirect when I type http://example.com it redirect to https://www.example.com
Below is my redirection in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
#Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$[OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Below are my logs:

```
init rewrite engine with requested uri /
pass through /
[perdir D:/wamp64/www/example/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/wamp64/www/example/ -> 
[perdir D:/wamp64/www/example/] applying pattern '.*' to uri ''
[perdir D:/wamp64/www/example/] RewriteCond: input='off' pattern='!on' => matched
[perdir D:/wamp64/www/example/] RewriteCond: input='www.example.com' pattern='^www\\.example\\.com$' => matched
[perdir D:/wamp64/www/example/] rewrite '' -> 'https://www.example.com/'
[perdir D:/wamp64/www/example/] explicitly forcing redirect with https://www.example.com/
[perdir D:/wamp64/www/example/] escaping https://www.example.com/ for redirect
[perdir D:/wamp64/www/example/] redirect to https://www.example.com/ [REDIRECT/301]
```

I also found that my website only redirect when I logout from VPN(I need to VPN so that I can connect to the server to fix or get the info that I have done for redirection)

Below is the item that I added in .htaccess file:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST] ^www\.example\.com$
    RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Below are my httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot "d:/wamp64/www/example"
    <Directory  "d:/wamp64/www/example/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My SSL certificate was configured in httpd-ssl.conf so I point my httpd-vhosts.conf as VirtualHost *:80
Below are my httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot "d:/wamp64/www/example"
    <Directory  "d:/wamp64/www/example/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

## Update

Below is what I update in .htaccess by adding [OR]:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

And below are the logs that I got:

```
strip per-dir prefix: D:/wamp64/www/example/ -> 
applying pattern '.*' to uri ''
RewriteCond: input='off' pattern='!on' => matched
rewrite '' -> 'https://www.example.com/'
explicitly forcing redirect with https://www.example.com/
escaping https://www.example.com/ for redirect
redirect to https://www.example.com/ [REDIRECT/301]
```

I have tried it again in browser but it wasn't redirected. I also try to debug in firefox and host I got is example.com

This is what I got by removing [OR]

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Logs:

```
RewriteCond: input='off' pattern='!on' => matched
RewriteCond: input='www.example.com' pattern='^example\\.com$' => not-matched
```

Please tell me that my redirection is working cuz I've been work in this for months and getting out of idea now(I hope is not because of my silly mistake...praying!). Please help me and thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `ServerAlias` option for your case? If yes than you could just put under Virtual host configuration  `ServerName  www.example.com  ServerAlias example.com  Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/`.

Comment: I did add server alias in my vhosts. but my ServerName is example.com and ServerAlias is www.example.com but actually what is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you don't actually want this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
```

Because that would cause an infinite redirect loop to itself, given this is from the `.htaccess` that applies to the `https://www` version, too:

```
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I thought the same thing at first, but that line is actually necessary in order to rewrite `http://www.example.com/` as `https://www.example.com/`. The infinite redirect loop ([which is definitely a real thing](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/RewriteLooping)) is prevented in this case by [lack of inheritance of mod_rewrite directives between VirtualHosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteengine). Most of the Linux distributions that I have seen configure the default SSL-enabled website using a separate VirtualHost.

Comment: I tried to remove the above lines and remain this line(RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$[OR]) but when tried in IE, my website still not redirecting when I type http+example.com

Comment: That's not necessary, because you have `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]`. If you removed the line, remember to remove the `[OR]` from the previous condition, too.

Comment: Hi Esa, nice to meet you! Here is what I got after remove line(RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$) and remain line(RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$), result->>([perdir D:/wamp64/www/example/] RewriteCond: input='off' pattern='!on' => matched
[perdir D:/wamp64/www/example/] RewriteCond: input='' pattern='^example\\.com$' => not-matched)

Comment: @EsaJokinen you are correct, the "!on" RewriteCond covers the `http://www.example.com/` to `https://www.example.com/` redirect. And the "redirected you too many times" message shows that I incorrectly assumed the VirtualHost setup in WAMP.

Comment: Hi, liverwust, nice to meet you! How are you doing today? I have added the item as requested.

Comment: Hello Petri, I am well. Based on your update, I think that you removed one too many [OR]s. Esa meant that you shouldn't have a "hanging" [OR] on the last RewriteCond. You still need it _between_ the RewriteConds. Please add [OR] to the %{HTTPS} !on condition.

Comment: I already update [OR] to the %{HTTPS} !on condition, but the website still didn't redirect when I type 'example.com' in the browser. I have update .htaccess and logs as above. It seems to ignore this condition:RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ I also added another info where rewritecond without [OR] and rewritecond input from logs is www.example.com but when I try it in Firefox debugger, the host that I got is example.com instead. I feel like the solution was so close yet so far.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is a missing space character. Please change this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$[OR]
```

to this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
```

Your logfile entries proved that http://www.example.com was successfully rewritten to https://www.example.com/. They didn't prove anything about http://example.com. Adding the space character should fix the latter.

Comment: I did try to add space but it ends up my website show www.example.com redirected you too many times.

Comment: I think you need to do this *plus* @EsaJokinen's suggestion. I see that you posted new log entries in the other comment thread, but if it is still not working then it might be more readable to add an "Update:" section to the question instead.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `mod_rewrite` you should use something like this in Virtualhost definition:

```
ServerName  www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com
Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
```

According to  [Apache httpd documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/avoid.html).

> mod_rewrite should be considered a last resort, when other alternatives are found wanting. Using it when there are simpler alternatives leads to configurations which are confusing, fragile, and hard to maintain.

Comment: Yes, is another solution as well but my configuration already using httpd-ssl.conf so I might think to stick with it unless I still can't work it out.

Comment: This is true. Also, if you have access to the server configuration, you should avoid using `.htaccess`. However, this answer is incomplete, because it's far from the question, and doesn't explain all the required steps.