# RewriteCond pattern all match and logs showing the correct redirect link but website still not redirect

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, 301-redirect

I have done N times of redirection and not successful for N times and now this is the most close to what I want but my website still wasn't redirect. I want my website to redirect from http+example.com to https+www.example.com
Below is my .htaccess redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On
#Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]also
```

This is the logs that I got:

```
RewriteCond: input='off' pattern='!on' => matched
RewriteCond: input='www.example.com' pattern='example.com' [NC] => matched
rewrite '' -> 'https://www.example.com/'
explicitly forcing redirect with https://www.example.com/
escaping https://www.example.com/ for redirect
redirect to https://www.example.com/ [REDIRECT/301]
```

The logs looks perfect and it is what I hope it redirect to but it wasn't. Also, when I scroll down deeper, I found some weird redirect as below:

```
rewrite 'ads.txt' -> 'https://www.example.com/ads.txt'
[Thu Apr 09 16:57:40.910510 2020] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 5472:tid 1148] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 66.249.79.219:43577] 66.249.79.219 - - [www.example.com/sid#5f3b3aead0][rid#5f3bc4a2c0/initial] [perdir D:/wamp64/www/example/] explicitly forcing redirect with https://www.example.com/ads.txt
```

The link itself is correct but why with ads.txt?
I also found this referrer which I don't know where it come from:

```
rewrite '' -> 'https://www.example.com/', referer: https://unknownsite.az/
explicitly forcing redirect with https://www.example.com/, referer: https://unknownsite.az/
```

I also notice it sometime rewritecond input with some IP address but I didn't define any IP address anywhere.
Please do help me on this, I know that I'm getting close to the answer.  Kindly help me and thanks in advance! Do let me know if you guys need any more info, I will update it accordingly.

Comment: "The logs looks perfect and it is what I hope it redirect to but it wasn't." - So, where did it redirect to? Are you seeing multiple redirects and just the last redirect is not as expected? Check the network traffic in the browser.

Comment: Yes, I do check but it just stops at http:example.com with host example.com and it seems to be multiple redirects, the redirect wasn't stopped there but it seems to keep on redirect endlessly in logs :(((

Comment: So, what is the redirect loop exactly? (You can see this in the browser developer tools.)

Comment: Hi MrWhite, I appreciate that you would spend this time with me. Actually, is me thought that it looping by looking at logs, but when tried in firefox debugger, it actually just stop at http://example.com. I'm kind of frustrated with this right now :(((

Comment: You keep struggling with the same problem day after day, asking essentially the same question in different forms [all](https://serverfault.com/q/1011208/274176) [over](https://serverfault.com/q/1010892/274176) [again](https://serverfault.com/q/1009940/274176). That's consequences of **not following the best practice [answers](https://serverfault.com/a/1011228/274176)** you have already received on your other questions.

Comment: So what response do you get? The redirect directives are not strictly correct (since the second condition sill/should always be successful - so it's only an HTTP to HTTPS redirect). "The logs looks perfect" - Actually, the logs don't "look perfect"... why is the input `www.example.com` when apparently requesting `example.com`? `[R=301,L]also` - erroneous text after the directive?!

Comment: @MrWhite: That's probably because the `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com [NC]` is also applied via `.htaccess` on a (matching) `www.example.com`, because it doesn't limit the condition with `^` at the beginning, causing a redirect loop.

Comment: My White, yes, I do get the hint from your previous comment. But I've tried like few times, from previous input ='' to input ='www.example.com' I trying hard to do it. Will try it again to make it input='example.com' and monitor if the redirection work.

Comment: Hi Esa, I know that I'm struggling a lot with the same problem. I'm sorry if this causing hassle to you guys but I do hope that I can fix this ASAP. So sorry if I'm causing so much trouble but I really do try my best to do it:((